# Ежедневно посещаЕт или посещаЮт — как правильно?

Tags: глаголы, управление, окончания

Как правильно:

> Лувр ежедневно посеща**ет** более 30.000 человек.

или же:

> Лувр ежедневно посеща**ют** более 30.000 человек.

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае желательно выбрать ед. число: **Лувр ежедневно посещает более 30.000 человек.**

Это связано прежде всего с препозицией сказуемого,  а также с тем, что подчеркивается  общее количество действующих лиц.

**Примечание (по Розенталю):** Раньше на выбор формы сказуемого (только в ед.ч.) влияли слова, обозначающие приблизительное количество (**около, свыше, больше, меньше**), однако в настоящее время используются оба варианта, например: "Не менее двадцати дам, иные с детьми, **сидели** на скамейках" (здесь препозиция подлежащего определяет форму мн.числа).

**Пример:** В год Сингапур посещает более 6 млн. туристов.

Comment: В ответе пропущена буква А (нА скамейках)